# Grouping duplicates and adding a weight column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with 2 million entries that looks like this:

```
Source / Target
A      / B
A      / B
C      / D
B      / C
C      / D
```

And I would like to obtain

```
Source / Target / Weight
A      / B      / 2
C      / D      / 2
B      / C      / 1
```

How would you advise me to do that?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple grouped query should do:

```
SELECT source, target, count(*) as weight
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY source, target
```

Comment: I think both of us know this question should be closed.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick answer. I am a newbie. Will this replace the current table or be copied in a new one?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO why should this question be closed? are you trying to say that this question shouldn't be answered at all?

Comment: @SkinnyPipes It shows no effort.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO It's up to someone if this question will be answered or not. Leave others to help.

Comment: @SkinnyPipes: if I was in a bad mood today, I'd have voted to close too. The morning's still young, though.

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
select source, target, count(*) as weight FROM table group by source, target
```